# Shell sed - "unterminated `s' command" in Windows / "unescaped newline inside substitute pattern" in MAC

Tags: windows, macos, powershell, shell, sed

I am trying to fix an old shell script that used to run on MAC to be runnable on Windows... But I am facing errors in both machines WRT one particular sed operation. The code snippet is :

```
echo "1 :: ${1}"
echo "2 :: ${2}"
sed -i.bak 's/^export \('${1}'=\)\(.*\)/export \1"'"$(sedscape ${2})"'"/' ~/.bash_profile
rm -f ~/.bash_profile.bak
```

The function sedscape is :

```
function sedscape() {
  echo " >>> sedscape"
  echo "1 :: ${1}"
  echo ${1//\//\\/} | sed 's/'\''/'\'\\\\\'\''/'
}
```

This gives me following error on Windows:

> 1 :: AWS_ACCESS_KEY
> 2 ::
> sed: -e expression #1, char 59: unterminated `s' command

and on MAC:

> 1 :: AWS_ACCESS_KEY
> 2 ::
> sed: 1: "s/^export (AWS_ACCESS_ ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern

.bash_profile has just one line :

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY="aaaa"
```

As far as I can understand, it is readin every line from .bash_profile starting with "export" and replacing the value of it with whatever is in "2" ... but it fails even before the "sedscape" half (second half) of the expression is evaluated.
Correct me if the understanding of the sed command is wrong.

PLEASE HELP !!!

Comment: Your understanding of the sed command is likely correct.  The original author's knowledge of sed was decidedly limited, and this code is... ugly.   Any sed replacement with `s///` can be recoded as `s###` or `s|||` or `s@@@` or any character other than `/` which is of course used rampantly in paths.

Comment: I worry, though, that special characters in that AWS key mean that you can't use replacement.  Better off deleting the line, and then replacing it.  `sed  -i.bak "/export $1/d" ~/.bash_profile; echo "export $1=$2" >> ~/.bash_profile` or some such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The echos in sedscape were creating the errors... simply removing them sloved the issue.

```
  echo " >>> sedscape"
  echo "1 :: ${1}"
```